# WCF Rest service not displaying methods on test client

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am writing a WCF Rest service to return a JSON message. I've been trying to use an example I found on the internet as a guide. Any time I fire up the test client, none of my methods are displayed. Navigating to the Uri while the service is running yields me a "page cannot be displayed" page. Not exactly too sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Web Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJasonP"
             crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="WcfRestLicense.LicenseService"
           behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJasonP"
              contract="WcfRestLicense.ILicenseService" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              address="mex" />

  </service>
</services>
<!--<client />-->

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<protocolMapping>
  <add
    scheme="http"
    binding="webHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJasonP" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment
  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Service method:

```
public IQueryable<customer> GetCustomerById(string customerId)
    {
        int custId = Convert.ToInt32(customerId);
        return _context.customers.Where(c => c.cust_id == custId);
    }
```

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILicenseService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "customer/{customerId}/",
        RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    IQueryable<customer> GetCustomerById(string customerId);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by test client you're talking about the `WcfTestClient`, then it won't work with RESTful services; it's designed to work with SOAP based web services.  You can test RESTful services in a browser by passing in the appropriate URI, something like this:

```
http://<location of your service>/service/1
```

Where the number 1 would be a customer ID.  This is a rough example as a) I don't do a lot with RESTful services and b) I'm not sure what your actual address is.

As far as getting a 404 when you go to the Uri, it sounds like you're looking for the help page.  You can enable that in your config file:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJasonP"
             crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" 
             enableHelp="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```